# jQuery - If Class Exists In Document, and If Its Empty

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to detect if there's an class in the document called `.modal-admin-content`, and I want to detect if it's empty (div of class does not contain content).

Now for that I'm using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if( $('.modal-admin-content').length ) {
        alert('exists');
        if( $('.modal-admin-content').is(':empty') ) {
            alert('empty');
        }
    }
});
```

`.modal-admin-content` is dynamically loaded through AJAX.

This code I have does not appear to detect the class. What would be the correct way to find the class in realtime?

Comment: If the JS code is also loaded via ajax, it must be evaluated first.

Comment: @Tyr The JS code is loaded through a static `<script>`